# SSL Installation Issues for 2 Web-servers in 1 Domain

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I have domain and 2 web-servers running on it with different port:
1) https://intellirehab.usim.edu.my (APACHE)
2) http://intellirehab.usim.edu.my:8081 (TOMCAT)

I have the SSL certificates for both of them; server.crt (for APACHE) and server.jks (for TOMCAT). I'm done the configuration part on APACHE server and 'HTTPS' just work fine for me. BUT, I'm trying to configure TOMCAT server to use SSL connection and it doesn't work. I am attempting to follow the instructions for setting up SSL in Tomcat 7 still doesn't work.

This is my server.xml file:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <!--<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" /> REMOVE IT IF USE KEYSTORE-->
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">


    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />


    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576" maxThreads="1000" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="conf/server.jks" keystorePass="*******" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    />


    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="intellirehab.usim.edu.my">


      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />
      </Realm>

      <Host name="intellirehab.usim.edu.my" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">


        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: What is meant by "it doesn't work"? This is to vague to provide a proper answer.
Is the server returning any SSL related errors?

Comment: its mean, the server not redirect to https.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem by configuring SSL in 8081 connector and remove the 8443 connector. Thanks!